# Bind a Textbox which is contained in a Groupbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, binding, textbox, groupbox

I have a Winforms App with a Groupbox which, in turn, contains a textbox. I find that the textbox will not bind when enclosed in the Groupbox, even though it does bind (correctly) when not contained in the Groupbox.

This is the case whether the binding is expressed in the Properties window or in the code. 
Has anyone else experienced this behavior or have an explanation for it?

Note that whether the textbox is enabled or not makes no difference.

From the Windows Designer.vb file:

```vb
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.Controls.Add(Me.HearingTypeTextBox)
{...}
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 109)
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.Name = "HearingInfoGroupBox"
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(333, 152)
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.TabIndex = 47
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.TabStop = False
    Me.HearingInfoGroupBox.Text = "Hearing Info"
{...}
    Me.HearingTypeTextBox.Enabled = False
    Me.HearingTypeTextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(112, 86)
    Me.HearingTypeTextBox.Name = "HearingTypeTextBox"
    Me.HearingTypeTextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(204, 20)
    Me.HearingTypeTextBox.TabIndex = 59
```

And from the Form code file (or the designer, if implemented through the Properties window):

```vb
    Me.HearingTypeTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.JuvPlacementDataBindingSource, "HearingType", True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to unrelated binding errors elsewhere on the form.  When they were resolved, the reported behavior disappeared.